# WPF C#, Handle mouse clicks and force clicks outside of application

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been searching around but unable to find a solution.

What i want to be able to do is

(1) If i click anywhere on the screen (outside form included), get the location of the mouse /cursor.
(2) To be able to move cursor and force mouse clicks outside of the form given coordinates of screen.

I just can't seem to find global event handlers. I've looked at hooks but dll returns in errors  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

i'm using .NET 4.6.1, Visual Studio 2017

[image]

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992245/mouse-cursor-outside-of-form) might help